# weird display under IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i know the IE6 is dead,but in china, there are lots of people still using it. so expect someone can do me a favor  about this problem.

this is the

http://run.xxmn.com/new/merchant.html

the 6 small pages move form left to right  under the header. there are 8 pages in the box. but under IE6,there are only 7 pages. the last one is under the first one, but under IE7,Firefox,chrome. it's display ok..

Comment: you mean under IE6 there are only 7 pages. May be you could post some css, that is related to that menu, as there are several css files on your site, and it's complicated to search the right one

Comment: yeah, under IE6 there are only 7 pages.but under  IE7,Firefox,chrome. it's display ok.

Comment: the effect is generated by a plugin.but in my stle.css file  i can use my style to overwrite the  plugin style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have IE 6 available right now, but it looks like double margin bug: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Possible fix:

```
#viewscarousel-blue_img-block_1 li {
    ..other rules..
    display:inline;
}
```

This would work for IE 5/6, and, AFAIR, won't produce any difference in modern browsers. But still it's better to use additional IE styles via Conditional Comments.